# File IO being slow

Tags: raid, performance, io

I've rented this root server with a RAID1 mdadm software raid setup.
Using dd to benchmark the file IO speed it achieves 230MB/s write (default blocksize). Certain tasks such as mysql are way slower, though, using iotop it averages at about 20KB/s.
To add to the weirdness, right at the beginning when the RAID array was still syncing the file access was at normal speed.
I guess this is only happenining wiht many small files.

As options on my / partition I use defaults,data=writeback,relatime

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks for help/answers!

Comment: How about CPU IO wait time when writing to SQL? Is there any?

Comment: How can I check this? Also, using nobarrier didn't make a difference.

Comment: You can run top or htop. In top you will notice (in CPU row): 'wa', it will tell you how much time (%) CPU spends on waiting for IO operations. In htop, you need to configure it by checking show detailed CPU time in the options (F2 to enter). If there is high IO time I'd put my money on storage subsystem bottleneck.